# How to prepare json or json array for api in .net core using httpclient

Tags: json, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I want to prepare a json like below using c#. I want to use it for post api call. How can I do it?

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "person": {
                "name": "xyz",
                "country": "india",
                "phone": "9999999999",                
            }
        },
        {
            "person": {
                "name": "abc",
                "country": "india",
                "phone": "8888888888",                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Where are you encountering problems. Did you do a proper search here to see if anyone has done this before?

Comment: I had search about it. We did it easily in node js but with c# i have no idea. I am not able to join the dots. I know we can do it with string concatenation but it is not proper solution. I want to do it by creating object and properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind json array from `appsetting.json` to `class`, you can use following code:

**create three models**

```
public class person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }

public class inputs
    {
        public person person { get; set; }
    }

public class conf
    {
        public inputs[] inputs { get; set; }
    }
```

**Inject them into container in `program.cs`(.Net 6)**

```
builder.Services.Configure<conf>(builder.Configuration);
```

**Then in your controller, Using `Dependency Injection` in the Constructor to Get the Value**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IOptions<conf> _option;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration,IOptions<conf> option)
        {
            
           _option = option;
        }
```

**Finally, You can use model's properties to get the value from `appsetting.json`**

[image]